# Dead Exchange 2010 organisation move to clean Exchange 2013

Tags: active-directory, exchange-2010, exchange-2013

The previous two Exchange servers in my client's Exchange Organisation have not been removed but are essentially dead and the company doesn't have a recent backup of the exchange data (not setup in this way by myself). They both had an Exchange 2010 server running on a virtual machine (Running Windows Server 2008 R2). One of the Exchange servers was in use the other was not.

We are now setting up a new physical server running Exchange server 2013 Sp1 and Windows 2012 R2. We have a server 2003 domain functionality level. We plan to export the local cached copy of users mailboxes from outlook into PST files and manually import these PST files into the new mailboxes on exchange 2013. 
We are not too sure what steps we need to do to ensure users active directory accounts will point to new mailboxes. I’m guessing we will need to create fresh mailboxes in exchange 2013 an attach these mailboxes to the users active directory accounts but will any reference information relating to the old mailbox already attached to the users need to be removed or will this be done automatically?
Any advise on this would be appreciated.

The Edge Transport role was on the old Exchange server that died; but there is a possibility we can get the machine restored.

Thanks

Comment: If the previous Exchange servers were simply lost, shut down, whatever but Exchange was not uninstalled and removed from the organization then you'll need to manually remove all traces of the previous Exchange installs from the organization.

Comment: Okay, there is a possibility that we may be able to get the data back from one of the Exchange servers, so we'd need to copy the information store over to the new server. Presumably if I remove all traces I would be relatively stuck if we do get this data recovered

Comment: Also, as edited... The Edge Transport role was on that server that died

Comment: It's not a big lost for the edge transport server, it's a server built to be in the DMZ and to leverage attack risk. You still have a living mailbox server ? If yes, you install the 2013 and migrate mailbox.

Comment: We have no current Exchange server what so ever. I am at the prompt on the Exchange server to select the roles but I can't have Edge Transport and Mailbox on the same machine according to the installer; when I select the mailbox role it greys-out the Edge Transport role

Comment: You told you got 1 server dead, the other is dead too ? If the other is dead all outlook will have difficulty connecting and would be in offline mode. And yes, you can install both role on same server, as I told the edge is there only to secure the receive connector in big. The statement 'One was in use while the other was not' make no sense too

Comment: @JoshPurcell
It's a very high-level overview on the environment. However, you could potentially, take an Exchange DB and mount it under a new server and export/use data within it. There's a lot of manual work involved and a lot of downtime, as it seems. In order to provide any more guidance, you would have to share more info.